# iPhone SDK: Stopping a Video

Tags: iphone, xcode, video, ios4

How can I stop a video once I navigate away from a view and make the video play again when I get back to the original view again?

Here is the code to play the video in the original view:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSBundle *bundle=[NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *moviePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"Video" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL *movieURL=[[NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath] retain];
    MPMoviePlayerController *theMovie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
    theMovie.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
    theMovie.view.frame = CGRectMake(104.0, 134.0, 200.0, 250.0);
    [self.view addSubview:theMovie.view];
    [theMovie play];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor viewFlipsideBackgroundColor];      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Make `theMovie` instance var
2. Stop playing in the `-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated`

And it should start playing when you navigate back to this view. Or move this code to `-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated`